# firebase realtime databse Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire2

In my service class I have a method to create a new user. I need to add an entry to the databse where the key is equal to the newly created user. I get this error `Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'src/app/models/users.model';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { mapFireBaseListResponse } from '../helpers/functions/map-firebase-list-response';
import { removePropFromObject } from '../helpers/functions/remove-prop-from-object';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

    path = '/users';
    listRef: AngularFireList<User>;

    constructor(
        private fireBase: AngularFireDatabase,
        private auth: AngularFireAuth
    ) {
        this.listRef = this.fireBase.list(this.path, ref => ref.orderByChild('active').equalTo(true));
    }

    getAllUsers = () => mapFireBaseListResponse(this.listRef);

    newUser = async (user: User) => {
        const authApp = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'NewUser');
        const created = await authApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
        const newUser = await this.fireBase.list(`/users/${created.user.uid}`).set(
            created.user.uid,
            removePropFromObject(user, 'password')
        );
        authApp.auth().signOut();
        return newUser;
    }

    updateUser = (user: User) => this.listRef.update(user.key, removePropFromObject(user, 'key'));

}
```

Comment: So, `created.user.id` is undefined?

Comment: @DougStevenson breakpoint shows that I do have a value for this. i think the error is referring to the database not having an entry with this key.

Comment: The full error is `core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.LBdbNL67lxQk8PZyFPHSPrPNxQA2.LBdbNL67lxQk8PZyFPHSPrPNxQA2.key'
Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.LBdbNL67lxQk8PZyFPHSPrPNxQA2.LBdbNL67lxQk8PZyFPHSPrPNxQA2.key'`

Comment: @SandraWillford can I see the implementation of your `removePropFromObject` function

Comment: @SeyiAdekoya I figured this out yesterday. I was sending a property 'key' to firebase with an undefined value. So this fixed it `.set(created.user.uid, {...user, key: null, password: null});` apparently firebase is fine with null, but not undefined.